# $f(f(\sqrt{2}))=\sqrt{2}$ then f has a fixed point

Tags: calculus, continuity

$f(x)$  is continuous $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

$f(f(\sqrt{2}))=\sqrt{2}$

Prove that $f$ has a fixed point

in other words prove the there is $x_1$ such that $f(x_1)=x_1$

---

I tried using $g(x)=f(x)-x$
and tried to use the Intermediate value theorem but did not succeed.
and it's obvious that $x=\sqrt{2}$ is the answer

Comment: I tried using g(x)=f(x)-x
and tried to use the mean value theorem but did not succeed.

Comment: Is this function continuous on a closed interval and differentiable on a open interval? Otherwise you can't use the mean value theorem.

Comment: sorry I meant Intermediate value theorem

Comment: You'd still have to make sure the function is defined at a closed bounded interval to use any theorem that deals with compactness. Were you given any information on the domain of your function, or wether its invertible (it seems to be...)?

Comment: "it's obvious that $x=\sqrt2$ is the answer" Not really. Suppose $f(x)=10-x$.

Comment: @FelipeJacob it is defined on R see I edited the post

Comment: @Rahul so what happens ?

Comment: Then $f$ is continuous and $f\big(f(\sqrt2)\big)=\sqrt2$, but $x=\sqrt2$ is not the fixed point of $f$.

Comment: wow I missed that thank you for pointing this out !

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $\alpha=f(\sqrt2)$. Show that $f(\alpha)=\sqrt2$. Inspect $f(x)-x$ at $\sqrt2$ and $\alpha$.

**For further enjoyment:** When you grok this question, try showing that if $$\overbrace{f\circ f\circ\cdots\circ f}^{n\text{ compositions}}(x_0)=x_0$$ then $f$ has a fixed point.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
and for solving the enjoyment do I need to write an algorithm to show that ?

Comment: @WasFr: Not really. It should only require the methods we have used for this question.

Comment: okay :D got the idea

Comment: @Sawarnik: we are given that $f(\alpha)=f(f(\sqrt2))=\sqrt2$.